# How to show size limit exceeded for Tomahawk FileInput control

Tags: jsf, file-upload, tomahawk

I am using `<t:inputFileUpload />` control of the Tomahawk library with JSF1.1.
My Extension Filters and form are set accordingly to allow a file of max-size 3 MB to be uploaded. But the problem is if a File is more than 3 MB the form doesnt get submitted but is shown again , and i cant set any `<h:message>` for it .

**So how do i tell the User the file upload has failed.**

I have tried keeping `<h:messages globalOnly="true"` but nothing gets shown.

I have followed [BalusC](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2008/02/uploading-files-with-jsf.html) blog post for setting up my uploads.

Answer (score 5):

The exception detail is available in EL by

```
#{requestScope['org.apache.myfaces.custom.fileupload.exception']}
```

So, adding the following component to the page should do it

```
<h:outputText value="File upload failed! #{requestScope['org.apache.myfaces.custom.fileupload.exception']}" 
    styleClass="error" rendered="#{not empty requestScope['org.apache.myfaces.custom.fileupload.exception']}" />
```

---

You could eventually create a `PhaseListener` which turns it into a `FacesMessage`. Do the following in `beforePhase()` of `PhaseId.RENDER_RESPONSE`

```
Object fileuploadException = requestMap.get("org.apache.myfaces.custom.fileupload.exception");
if (fileuploadException != null) {
    facesContext.addMessage(null, new FacesMessage("File upload failed! " + fileuploadException));
}
```

Comment: Thank you for such a detailed reply. However I am sorry to say I am getting #{requestScope['org.apache.myfaces.custom.fileupload.exception']} as null when I encounter a File size exception. I am using JSF : 1.1_02-b08

Comment: this works, I use validade in js to and backend with this code. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10508477/restricting-file-upload-size-in-jsf/57906775#57906775